# deploy android application on to real device

Tags: android, netbeans

I want to deploy my android application on to real mobile device by using netbeans how can i do it.

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/procedure_for_android_development_on - gives some steps to make it work :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how you would do with NetBeans, since I guess NetBeans doesn't have adb integration and you have to do all the things with console (I don't know exactly)

But you can do it with:

```
$./adb install -d <path_to_ur_app.apk>
```

Tell me, have you configured your device USB drivers (If on Windows) on your system?

Which OS you're on?

Comment: Open up the SDK Manager and download the 'Android USB Cable Driver' from it. let it download and install the drivers. then connect your device and use above steps. revert if you need more help.

Comment: or send it in Bluetooth and install it. But adb install is the best way

Comment: how can i doenload Android USB cable driver?i Had opened SDK manager but im unable to find an option to download usb cable driver

Comment: which SDK Manager you have? the latest one?

Comment: how can i deploy my application

Comment: Did you use a zip file to install it? if yes, then tell its full name. or if u used an exe, then it surely is the latest.

Comment: anyway, whichever you have, open it, and go to 'Available Packages' option. there, you'll see the 'Android USB Cable Driver' as available package, if it's not already install. click it and 'install' it

Comment: yaaa its installed after it what should i do?

Comment: No simply connect your device, enable USB debugging in your device (Settings>applications>development) and check whether your device is recognised or not. for this, use the command "adb devices" and all the devices will be listed.

Comment: You'll have to use "adb" command from the command line, "cmd" in ur windows, and will have to locate adb tool. if your SDKManager is lates, it will be in android-sdk/platfrom-tools directory

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who is reading this old question - there is Netbeans plugin with quite nice ADB integration: http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend to use Eclipse IDE because Google provides a plugin for developing and deploying your apps from within the IDE.

Just follow [these](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) steps and you can't run into any trouble ;)

Or is there any special reason why you prefer Netbeans for mobile development?

Comment: So I found this for you... [Google HowTo WinUSB](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)